# Azure AD B2C: The scope 'files.read' provided in the request is not supported

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I set up my scopes for my maui authorization app like this:
[image]

But when I set them up in my constants I am being returned:

```
public static readonly string[] Scopes = { "files.read", "files.write", };

if (IdentityClient == null)
        {

            IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(Constants.ClientId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
                .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn)
                .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
                .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
                .Build();

        }

        var accounts = await IdentityClient.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        bool tryInteractiveLogin = false;

        try
        {
            result = await IdentityClient
                .AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();           
        }
```

An MSAL EXECPTION:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADB2C90117: The scope 'files.read' provided in the request is not supported.\r\nCorrelation ID: 23bba783-6562-4111-b097-9282a48e04c6\r\nTimestamp: 2023-06-27 14:56:31Z\r\n"}
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD B2C Mobile Application** and exposed API like below:

[image]

**Now**, I tried to generate the **access token** using the same scopes as you and got the same error:

```json
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signinsignup/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:xxxx
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:files.read files.write
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid scope while generating the access token.

**To resolve the error,** make sure to pass the scope like below:

```http
scope: https://sristackb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.read https://sristackb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.write
```

***I am able to generate the access token successfully like below:***

[image]

When I decoded the token, **scopes** are displayed:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your input. HOwever, I am not using postman for this request, I am using the official microsoft libraries in c#- all I can do is give the scopes like this:  .AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())- What do I need to alter here?

Comment: Change this line `public static readonly string[] Scopes = { "files.read", "files.write", };` to this `public static readonly string[] Scopes = { "https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.read", "https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.write", };`

Comment: this did fix this issue, however, If I try to access my functions with this token all I get it is a JSON reader exeption. So no authorized or unauthorized, just that It cant deal with the result ...